# Assigning direct string to char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, variable-assignment

In 2D array, assigning direct string to char array, getting an error.

```
char name[5][10];
name[0] = "hello";
```

But, using `strcpy`, copy the string to char array working fine.

```
char name[5][10];
strcpy(name[0],"hello");
```

Why first case not working?

Comment: There are tons of Questions like this on SO.

Comment: Can we please have a better dupe? That is too much inclined to C++.

Comment: Thats not a DUP

Comment: @Michi indeed, but now that it's closed and I'm thinking about it, there *must* be one ...

Comment: hopefully fixed the dupe link to something suitable

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: huh?

Comment: @FelixPalmen It seems that you and I are doing something similar at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, an array type is not a modifiable lvalue, hence cannot be "assigned".

An assignment operator needs a modifiable lvalue as the LHS operand.

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.16

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

and, chapter §6.3.2.1

> [....] A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
>   **does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a constqualified
>   type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
>   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a constqualified
>   type.

In your case, for an array defined like

```
char name[5][10];
```

the element `name[0]` is of type `char [10]`, that is, an array of 10 `char`s.

Comment: Probably it will be interesting to mention about `strcpy` and how it works. Maybe then the OP will understand more clearly why it works with `strcpy` and why it does not work with its approach. :)

Comment: @Michi well, that would be too much (too broad). OP already claims to know why strcpy works but not direct assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Because C does not allow to assign to an array. It's a limitation in the language.

Note that you **can** assign to a `struct`, even if it **contains** an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct x
{
    char s[20];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct x x;
    x = (struct x){ "test" };
    puts(x.s);
}
```